# Can't make Spring's ImportAware to work

Tags: spring, configuration

I am trying to create my own @EnableXxx-style annotation (namely @EnableCustomizedPropertySources). For this the annotation imports the class CustomizedPropertySourcesConfiguration which in turn implements [ImportAware](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ImportAware.html), in order to have access to attributes of the @EnableCustomizedPropertySources annotation.

Annotation:

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Import(CustomizedPropertySourcesConfiguration.class)
public @interface EnableCustomizedPropertySources {

    String externalFolderName();

    String propertiesFileName();

    (...)
}
```

Imported configuration class:

```
@Configuration
public class CustomizedPropertySourcesConfiguration implements ImportAware {

    protected AnnotationAttributes enableCustomizedPropertySourcesAttributes;

    @Override
    public void setImportMetadata(AnnotationMetadata importMetadata) {
        Map<String, Object> attributes = importMetadata.getAnnotationAttributes(EnableCustomizedPropertySources.class.getName(), false);
        this.enableCustomizedPropertySourcesAttributes = AnnotationAttributes.fromMap(attributes);
    }

    @Bean
    public PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySource() {
      return (...);
    }
}
```

The problem is, the method setImportMetadata is not invoked by Spring when I annotate some @Configuration class with my @EnableCustomizedPropertySources annotation, so I cannot access the annotations attributes.

Comment: I can see that ImportAware interface is handled by ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.ImportAwareBeanPostProcessor, which is a built-in BeanPostProcessor of Spring.
It turns out that my class CustomizedPropertySourcesConfiguration above is not being considered a bean (indeed as far as I understand `@Configuration` classes are not bean by themselves) however, when debugging this with other Spring's `@EnableXxx` annotations, the `@Configuration` classes imported by them are in fact handled by this BeanPostProcessor.

Comment: Have you been able to resolve this? I'm facing the same issue...

Comment: In a way. I still can't make it to work when using Spring Boot, but it worked with non-boot applications. I tried to debug deeper the Spring code but it got too low level for me to understand. My only guess is that there must be some kind of difference when Boot elects classes that must become beans, so that when ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.ImportAwareBeanPostProcessor‌ is invoked, the configuration class that implements ImportAware is not considered a bean and so is not processed.

Answer (score 1):

The `ImportAware` class (CustomizedPropertySourcesConfiguration) needs both:

```java
@Configuration
@Component
```